# Finding the maximum depth of a tree?

Tags: java

I have mapping of routes in the given form

```
(a d)
(a b)
(b a)
(b c)
(b e)
(b f)
(c b)
(d a)
(e b)
(e g)
(g e)
(g f)
(f g)
(f b)
```

[where (a,d) means record a connects to record d]

Connecting all this from a graph structure. I want to find the maximum depth of the graph structure. This has to be implemented using java.

Comment: have you tried it so far?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far. SO is not here to do your homework. Nevertheless I'm sure there are enough algorithms on the internet if you google for it.

Comment: i have tried it. Got very close to it but got an exception at the end.And have no idea how to rectify it.

Comment: If (a b) and (b a) is connected then there is a circle which implies that this structure is not a tree.

Comment: Then show us what you tried and ofc also the Exception

Comment: So cant i find the maximum depth of it?

Comment: It still is some kind of graph, therefore you could calculate the max distance from one Node (e.g. a).

Comment: Do you have a given root? Else you have to do a max distance search as @ceekay stated.

Comment: There is no given root. And i need to find the max distance search. @Flown

Comment: @ceekay any algorithms i can find for max distance search?

Comment: "i have tried it. Got very close to it but got an exception at the end.And have no idea how to rectify it" fixing that problem is what you should be asking us to help you with

Comment: I tried pasting my code here but it shows error while editing. Any suggestions why this is happening?  @ceekay

Answer (score 0):

Just use Depth First Search, and keeping an map of visited nodes (to avoid cycles). Just go deeper as long as the next child is not visited yet. Return 1 + child depth ( 0 in leaf nodes).

Comment: But i don't have a defined root node in my graph structure so i am confused from where should i start my DFS.

Comment: If you have no explicit root and still want to find the maximum distance you probably have to run it each time with a different root and compare the values.

Comment: Maximum distance will not give the depth of the graph structure. That just gives the longest route possible and that is far more than the depth of the graph. @ceekay

Comment: I just tried to explain the thoughts of Depth First without one specific root ;). The "problem" with your graph is that even if we reduce every `(x y)` `(y x)` to a single connection between the two nodes, you still have a cycle `(b e g f b)`. Therefore i guess there is no simple depth. The only thing i can think of is *Tree decomposition*, which possibly allowes you to perform such requests (see also *treewidth* and *tree-depth*)

Comment: This is just a sample. In real i have thousand of such entries, It is basically the route network of an entire country and i need an approximate depth of it. Tree decomposition will be too much  complex.